# unable to parse json string using java script eval function

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am facing issue with the following Json reponse object in the javascript eval function;Getting java script error expected }
because of special characters **Tamás** and **Török**

```
{
  [{
    "userFirstNm": "Naresh",
    "userAsscId": "70336",
    "userLastNm": "Yashwantrao",
    "userLanId": "a70336"
  }, {
    "userFirstNm": "Tamás",
    "userAsscId": "37732",
    "userLastNm": "Török",
    "userLanId": "a37732"
  }]
}
```

Is there is any solution to resolve this problem.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you show the code that's giving you errors? I tried this in my Firebug console and it behaved nicely.

Comment: I can't imagine this would not work.

Comment: that shouldn't be a problem i think so... Are you using jquery to parse it?

Comment: That is not valid JSON. Is it possible that you didn't want the outer braces?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah I know what the problem is. You need to wrap the object expression in parentheses for `eval` to work correctly.

```
alert(eval("({\"userFirstNm\":\"Tamás\",\"userAsscId\":\"37732\",\"userLastNm\":\"Török\",\"userLanId\":\"a37732\"})"));
```

Answer (score 0):

That isn't a JavaScript statement by itself, so you won't be able to eval it.

This Perl program runs the JavaScript in SpiderMonkey:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use JavaScript::SpiderMonkey;
my $stuff = '{"userFirstNm":"Tamás","userAsscId":"37732","userLastNm":"Török","userLanId":"a37732"}';

my $stuff2 = "var k = new Object ($stuff)";

my $js2 = JavaScript::SpiderMonkey->new();
$js2->init();  # Initialize Runtime/Context
my $rc2 = $js2->eval($stuff2);
print "$@\n";
```

This doesn't print any error messages.

The following:

```
my $js = JavaScript::SpiderMonkey->new();
$js->init();  # Initialize Runtime/Context
my $rc = $js->eval($stuff);
print "$@\n";
```

produces

```
Error: SyntaxError: invalid label at line 1: {"userFirstNm":"Tam��s","userAsscId":"37732","userLastNm":"T��r��k","userLanId":"a37732"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the string into a variable, and then put it into a var

```
var str = '{"userFirstNm":"Tamás","userAsscId":"37732","userLastNm":"Török","userLanId":"a37732"}';
eval("var obj=" + str);
console.debug ? console.debug(obj) : alert(obj); //outputs the object
```

And a safer alternative is the json_parse function: http://www.json.org/json_parse.js;

```
var obj = json_parse('{"userFirstNm":"Tamás","userAsscId":"37732","userLastNm":"Török","userLanId":"a37732"}');
console.debug ? console.debug(obj) : alert(obj); //outputs the object
```